# kdb q - lookup in nested list

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Is there a neat way of looking up the key of a dictionary by an atom value if that atom is inside a value list ?

Assumption: The value lists of the dictionary have each unique elements

Example:

```
d:`tech`fin!(`aapl`msft;`gs`jpm) / would like to get key `fin by looking up `jpm
d?`gs`jpm / returns `fin as expected
d?`jpm    / this doesn't work unfortunately
$[`jpm in d`fin;`fin;`tech] / this is the only way I can come up with
```

The last option does not scale well with the number of keys

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take advantage of how `where` operates with dictionaries, and use `in` :

```
where `jpm in/:d
,`fin
```

Note this will return a list, so you might need to do `first` on the output if you want to replicate what you have above.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you making this difficult on yourself? Use a table!

```
q)t:([] c:`tech`tech`fin`fin; sym:`aapl`msfw`gs`jpm)
q)first exec c from t where sym=`jpm
```

You *can* of course do what you're asking:

```
first where `jpm in'd
```

but this doesn't extend well to vectors while the table-approach does!

```
q)exec c from t where sym in `jpm`gs
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can take advantage of the `value` & `key` keywords to find what you're after:

```
q)key[d]where any value[d]in `jpm
,`fin
```

Hope that helps!

Jemma

Comment: can use an each right to speed this up but not as readable: key[d] where `jpm in/: value d

Answer (score 1):

The answers you have received so far are excellent. Here's my contribution building on Ryan's answer:

`` {[val;dict]raze {where y in/:x}[dict]'[val]}[`msft`jpm`gs;d] ``

The main difference is that you can pass a list of values to be evaluated and the result will be a list of keys.

`` [`msft`jpm`gs;d] ``

Output:

`` `tech`fin`fin ``